# Calculate multiple seating prices based on form selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a ticket booking form that updates pricing dynamically based on user input.

So far, what I've been able to get to work is filtering the options based on combinations of what the user has selected (which is based on certain criteria).

The next thing I need to do is somehow make the table calculate the individual seating prices based on the quantity selected and type of ticket, and then add them up for a total price.

I've made an attempt at creating an associative array which defines the price of each type of ticket based on certain criteria:

```
//price of seating
function getPrices(day, time) {
    var day = $('#whichDay').val(); // gets day value
    var time = $('#whichSession').val(); //gets time value
    var prices = new Array(); // creates the array

    if (day == 'mon' || day == 'tue' || time == '1pm') {
        prices["SA"] = 12;
        prices["SP"] = 10;
        prices["SC"] = 8;
        prices["FA"] = 25;
        prices["FC"] = 20;
        prices["B1"] = 20;
        prices["B2"] = 20;
        prices["B3"] = 20;
    } else {
        prices["SA"] = 18;
        prices["SP"] = 15;
        prices["SC"] = 12;
        prices["FA"] = 30;
        prices["FC"] = 25;
        prices["B1"] = 30;
        prices["B2"] = 30;
        prices["B3"] = 30;
    }
    return prices;
}
```

The problem is that I'm unsure where to go from here or if I've even created the table appropriately so that it allows this kind of calculation.

There's a lot to work with so I've created a fiddle for you guys to play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/qtsxkgrw/2/

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using knockout ? Do check this out: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html

Answer (score -1):

First of all, for the love of God please stop using tables. :D

Your solution might be to use the data attributes.
Soemthing like this in your HTML:

```
<input  data-price="99.99"    type="checkbox" class="ticketType" name="FA" value="FA"><span class="first-class">First Class </span> - Adult</td>
```

And get the value using:

```
var price = $(this).data("price");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Stop using tables??? Tables are VALID html and are ideal for presenting TABULAR data, like a pricing table.

Comment: That was a recommendation not the answer to his question, so this doesn't explain the downvote.

Comment: My bad! Sorry about that!